# Server side validation results appear in the same browser window

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Simple HTML form:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post" name="my_form" id="my_form" >
    <input name="c_name" type="text" id="c_name"  maxlength="90"/>
 </form>
```

test.php with the following code:

```
<?php
    $name=$_POST['c_name'];
    if ((!isset($name)) || ($name==''))
    {
      echo 'Fill in the name';        
    }
    else
    {
      echo $name;
    }
?>
```

Now, I want the following upon form submission:

1) Not to leave the current browser window as PHP to display the corresponding message.I want the form window to stay there.

2)I do not want just a simple response message. For example, I want instead of "Fill in the name" a more graphical way to interact like making a hidden div to appear; in other words I want to write Jquery inside PHP and make it execute. Is it possible and how?

I know I have to use AJAX, however I do not know what to do exactly! Could you give me some code as to realise the above two things?

Comment: Do your validation on the form, using JavaScript and/or JQuery. Don't submit until all validation and fancy error-messaging is done. This way server will only have to process and not do fancy client side things.

Comment: That is good advice, but also regex and learn basics. It'll come to you faster than you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if you're new to all of this, as you seem to are, you are best of using jQuery indeed. An ajax example can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Code in this case is q bit extensive. Cause you would not only want to check if it is in fact empty, but you also want to preg_match it. Which means you want to make sure that what your users send you actually want (and not break or hack or inject your server, which is important).

So seeing this I would recommend to read a tutorial, something like this (fast google search): http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery--net-6289

And familiarize yourself with some basics before getting into the next steps.

Answer (score 0):

To get the effect you are wanting. I like to use the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/), it makes it easy to create an AJAX form out of any existing form. Then simply echo your results in the .php file you submit to (Hint: you can echo div's with styling too.) The below example, assuming you have the jQuery Form Plugin included on your page, will submit the form using AJAX and return the echoed results to a div with id=status.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var status = $('#status');
    $('#my_form').ajaxForm({
        beforeSend: function() {
            status.empty();
        },
        complete: function(xhr) {
            status.html(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```